# How to select column names in webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriverio. I need to select column names for a table which is defined as `div` tags in UI grid instead of `tr`, td. I am able to select the number of available column names as 6 with below `xPath` but when I execute the same `xPath` I am getting available elements as 1.

```
fundSearchTable(){ 
  return $$("//ag-grid-angular//*[@class='ag-header-container']//*[@class='ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable']//*[@class='ag-header-cell-text']")
} 
const fundColumnList= await this.fundSearchTable; 
console.log("number of childs:"+ await fundColumnList.length) //logs 1
```

[Inspect in DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epWv0.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epWv0.png)

[image]
[image: Page]

Can someone help me with this as I need to interact with tables more often?

Comment: How are you determining you are only getting one element? Can you share the the relevant test code?

Comment: I am trying to print the number of elements returned from the browser. const fundColumnList= await this.fundSearchTable;
      console.log("number of childs:"+ await fundColumnList.length) ,  Xpath for  get fundSearchTable(){ return $$("//ag-grid-angular//*[@class='ag-header-container']//*[@class='ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable']//*[@class='ag-header-cell-text']")}

Answer (score 0):

As you posted images it is difficult to write the `xPath`. Please use below `xPath's` to select the column names.

`//span[text()='Fund Number']` or `//div[@col-id='fundNumber']`

`//span[text()='Fund Name']` or `//div[@col-id='fundName']`

`//span[text()='Fund Acronym']` or `//div[@col-id='fundAcronym']`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need to validate columns returned from the table . With my above xpath I am getting number of elements returned as  2 and but for rare times as 6. I tried to pause the browser to load the page. But it's not working.

Comment: Is it possible to share URL? If no then please share the HTML of the page (no screenshot). Add the HTML to the question

Comment: I am able to get 6 elements but when I try to print the element text name inside the loop I am getting error. But I am able to print the name without any loop.console.log("first element name is:"+await fundColumnList[1].getText())--->returning the text but when I try with loop like for(var i=0;i<=fundColumnList.length ;i++) {console.log("webelement is:"+ await fundColumnList[i].getText())} it's printing all the 6 elements but throwing the error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this. Issue was that the page is not loading by the time the command is executed to get the column names. I gave the wait time. And for the "for loop", I gave the length as `row.length-1`.
But still my result was inconsistent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).